# Site-wide page load event

Tags: asp.net, pageload

I have something that should be run at every page_load event in an aspx application, how would I go about doing this, I've looked in the asax file but I can't find what I want...

I specifically want to hook up some javascript code depending on the user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a base class that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page (you will put your javascript in that base class)

Then in each of your aspx pages, simply have the page derive from your base class.

Comment: I was trying to override the Onload event from the page, but I'm trying to use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` and I can't use the first argument because I need the page, and EventArgs doesn't contain the page I think...

Comment: use ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript...
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(YOURBASECLASSNAME), "UNIQUEMETHOD", "SCRIPT GOES HERE", true);

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [MasterPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) and have every page in your site inherit that MasterPage. Be aware of the [order of events in Master/Content pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx)